# Getting didSelectRowAtIndexpath method called when textfield inside custom table view cell is focused

Tags: iphone, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0

I have a custom tableviewcell with a label and a textfield. Right now I get callback in method didSelectRowAtIndexpath only when user clicks on cell outside of my textfield. When I touch on textfield this method is not called. So what should I do to get that method called when user touches on the textfield.

Comment: Did you ever solve this? many years later and I am running into the same issue...

Answer (score 2):

You want to read into [UITextFieldDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/UITextFieldDelegate/UITextFieldDelegate.html) and more specifically

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
```

and

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
```

when those get called you can then do this on your [UITableView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

```
– selectRowAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition:
```

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. But the problem is that I have many rows in my tableview. So how can I determine for each textfield that in which row it is? To do that I'll have to make instances for every textfield n will have to relate it to row number. I hope you will understand the problem.

Comment: When the delegate is called it passes itself (UITextField) as a parameter, either tag them cell.textField.tag = indexPath.row + c or if you have the references at your tableView compare them...

Answer (score 1):

In cellForRowAtIndexPath method write

```
cell2.selectionStyle=UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
```

for that row only

Comment: Sorry I can't understand your answer. Will you please elaborate this?

Comment: you have table view's delegate method - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath right?

Comment: I think you do not have understood my question. Please read it once again.

Comment: This solved my issue thanks.
However the new Swift Syntax is :


cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None